# issue in the return value in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to check the occurrence of a control in this function , but every time it returns value as `"0"` even when the text exists:

```
private int FindOccurenceCheckbox(string substr)
{

    string reqstr = Request.Form.ToString();
    substr = "CheckBoxdll";
    return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length) / substr.Length);
}
```

This is the value of `reqstr`:

> "_*EVENTTARGET=ddlcontrols&*_EVENTARGUMENT=&_*LASTFOCUS=&*_VIEWSTATE=%2fwEPDwUKLTIyNjcyOTI5MA9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAQIBZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAQUNQ2hlY2tCb3hkbGwtMZACzpLykGbncLmfD8JMOBwmVx5N&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2fwEWCwKztfT0BALBjeFfAuPA7qsFAs3fv6cLAuuY2OwBApPqidAEApyFo74IAp2Fo74IAp6Fo74IAr7h3OcDAr%2fmspEDoBBLBtCm1eeskKSim6Nd20%2bdpso%3d&ddlcontrols=Dropdown&ddlDynamic-1=&txtDynamic-1=&CheckBoxdll-1=on"

Can any one help me out? Why this always returns the value `"0"`?

Comment: Why does your method have a `substr` argument? You set it to `"CheckBoxdll"` inside the method!

Comment: It should return 1 in your example. Did you actually see (while debugging) reqstr containing that value? I ran your code by assigning a `string reqstr` the value you posted, and the method returns `1`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). If the value of `(reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length)` is less than the value of `substr.Length`, this will always return `0`. Even if the division was not integer, the result would be truncated because the return value of your method is `int`.

**Update:**

This answer has gathered a number of comments stating that integer division would not be a problem *if the `reqstr` and `substr` variables have the values the question provides* (the division would still be integer, but it would return a positive integer instead of `0`). This is certainly true, but it is also true that if you are receiving `0` then that is because the result of the division is also `0`.

Therefore, I believe that there is no explanation other than that some part of what the question provides as fact is simply not true (e.g. the contents of the two strings).

Comment: How can the value of `(reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length)` ever not be a multiple of `substr.Length`?

Comment: @dtb: Beats me. I can only speculate that the value of `reqstr` or `substr` is not what the question says it is. The code looks too simple to allow any other explanation.

Comment: @downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment.

Comment: -1 : I agree with dtb. Integer division has nothing to do with this problem. Since some think this is a good answer and I see that this answer as irrelevant for the question, I choose to downvote to compensate for the upvotes...

Comment: @erikH: I understand your concern, although I could argue that the answer hits the nail on the head in the sense that the "If the value of..." sentence describes exactly what's going on. Do you find the update an improvement?

Comment: @Jon Well, Kumee has a problem, but it's not with integer division as this answer suggests. Ergo this answer doesn't help. My downvote remains (to compensate). But I agree to your final conclusion. The content of the reqstr variable is most likely not what the question tells. (As comecme commented.)

Answer (score 1):

Nice way of thinking. I have ran your code and seems to be returning `1` on key exists and `0` on if it doesn't.

If checking the existence of the key in the `Request.Form` is your sole interest then you can do it in more concise and interesting way. Try this:

```
private bool FindOccurenceCheckbox(string substr)
{
    return Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(substr);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As Iridium identified a point that to count number of `CheckBoxdll-*`. Noting down an update with LINQ.

```
private int FindOccurenceCheckbox(string substr)
{
    return Request.Form.AllKeys.Count(p=>p.StartsWith(substr));
}
```

Comment: I think the purpose of the original code was to determine the number of times it appears, not just if it does or not.

Comment: can't have multiple items in a `Request.Form`

Comment: You'll note that the search is for "CheckBoxdll", whereas the example form data contains "CheckBoxdll-1". Presumably there could also be "CheckBoxdll-2", "CheckBoxdll-3", etc. and the goal is to determine how many there are.